# drawinrect vs directly setting up the value

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, uikit

When do you use drawinrect for a string or image versus directly setting the value? For example, I can have a uilabel and use its text for string or I can use [somestring drawInRect:somerect]. Similarly, I can use [someimage drawInRect:rect] or someview.backgroundImage where available.

Answer (score 0):

I would say using drawInRect method is "rare", this method is used for developping games or displaying maps with tons of texts for instance.

The thing is if you are displaying something simple like a form with textfield, uiswitch, etc... (if you don't do complex drawing) you should use UILabel.

Explain your project, we'll be able to help you in a better way than the things I said.

Remember : UILabel is meant to display strings ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am developing a game but it does not have complex graphics or such. But still wondering what we loose or gain by using drawInRect